# Can I only combine js files with encore?

Tags: javascript, symfony, npm, webpack-encore

I have symfony project with twitter bootstrap template (hardcoded assets in twig). I would like manage assets with Encore, but if encore process file, make module and next compilation magic.

Is any way how to config Encore for only combine js, without compilation?

Basic install Encore:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html

...and my idea, in file app.js:

```
include '1-file.js'; // alert(1);
include '2-file.js'; // alert(2);
```

and output in twig:

```
merged.js // alert(1); alert(2);
```

thanks for any advice

Comment: Did you try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50636234/symfony-webpack-encore-multiple-js-css-files-to-one-file

Comment: @TimZwinkels yes, a try set files in webpack.config.js in one entry as array, but encore make from every file module and break associations between files, i need only merge, without magic

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with encore for many months, when you run `yarn build` or `npm run build`, encore minimize those files. In **webpack.config.js** you have an option called enableSingleRuntimeChunk(). This option says to the system that, in case of a big file, encore will split the file in two for optimize the process. If you want to disable, remove the previous line and write .disableSingleRuntimeChunk().

Don't forget to run encore again to save this changes!!